# Javascript: Why if statement does not evaluate the hoisted variable in function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

AFAIK, variable declarations are hoisted in the context in which they are defined however, in the following code, [taken from here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

```
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
    if (!foo) {
        var foo = 10;
    }
    alert(foo);
}
bar();
```

`if(!foo)` evaluates to `true` but why? I mean `var foo` already exists from this statement`var foo = 10` before `if(!foo)` is evaluated in foo's context therefore `if(!foo)` should resolves to `if(!true)`, further resolves to `if(false)` that means the if block should not be executed but `if (!foo)`
 evaluates true hence the code within if block is executed and alerts 10

Can anybody tell me why and importantly how the if condition is evaluated ?

Comment: you are confusing me

Comment: From quickly skimming over the article linked, it's explained there..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to [Javascript "Hoisting"](https://www.sitepoint.com/back-to-basics-javascript-hoisting/) and it's annoying ability to do thinks that do not look like are being done :)

So, what is happening it that Javascript has no block scope for if clauses and it compensated for that in a weird way. I mean,  when you do

```
function bar() {
    if (!foo) {
        var foo = 10;
    }
    alert(foo);
}
```

it is actually translated to:

```
function bar() {
    var foo;
    if (!foo) {
      foo = 10;
    }
    alert(foo);
}
```

Before being executed, so that all variables are declared before usage. Based on that, `foo` will be `undefined` and *not* the global value declared outside the function. So when you call `if (!foo)`, it will be evaluating `!undefined`, which is always `true`.

Comment: Please note that both variables and function declarations are hoisted to the top of the given scope in ES5.  As such, I prefer to follow Crockford's recommendation of _writing_ all function and var declarations at the top of the scope, so that what is written is analogous to what is happening.  It's a convention, not a rule, but I find it simplifies reading of code.

Comment: @anied exactly! And kudos for citing Crockford's recommendation :)

Answer (score 0):

this one will give you 1;

```
function bar() {
    var foo =1;
    if (!foo) {
        var foo = 10;
    }
    alert(foo);
}
bar();
```

because variable foo declared in the function not out ;)
and this will give you 1 too :

```
var foo = 1;
function bar(x) {
    if (!x) {
        var x = 10;
    }
    alert(foo);
}
bar(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

When the foo function is compiled, there is another declaration of the foo variable. Due to hoisting of the variable in the function, the variable foo will be assigned the value of `undefined` until the code is executed.

The if statement is checking if the `foo` is *falsey*, as the variable is `undefined` at that point in time it is *falsey* so goes into the if statement where the value 10 is assigned to `foo`.

Changing `foo` in the inner function has no effect on the global variable due to scope.